# Create one id variable for each dataframe in a list of dataframes with name of each dataframe

Tags: r, data-frame

I have a list of dataframes. For each dataframe I want to create one new variable or column called uniqueid and I want this unique id to be the name of the dataframe from the list. I have tried the following but it does not work.

```
# List all shapefiles
dfs <- Filter(function(x) is(x, "data.frame"), mget(ls()))

for( i in seq_along(dfs)){
  dfs[[i]]$uniqueid<-print(paste(dfs[[i]]))
}
```

When I do the following each dataframe get a uniqueid equals to ID. SO I guess the part that is not working correctly on my code is `print(paste(dfs[[i]]))` however I can't figure out what the right fix is.

```
# List all shapefiles
dfs <- Filter(function(x) is(x, "data.frame"), mget(ls()))

for( i in seq_along(dfs)){
  dfs[[i]]$uniqueid<-'ID'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to query your list `names` at each iteration:

```r
library(sf)
# the files
fl = list.files("/dir_with_shapes", pattern = ".shp", full.names = T)

dfl = lapply(fl, read_sf) # read them in
names(dfl) = basename(fl) # give them the file name

for(i in seq_along(dfl))
   dfl[[i]]$df_name = names(dfl)[i]

df = do.call(rbind, dfl)  # bind them all together
```

Comment: Elio, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately the .shp are not in the same folder but in several (300+) different folders.

Comment: `list.files(..., recursive = TRUE)` would work if your files are all within the same parent directory; if you are not merging them all you may choose them by a pattern; besides that, you may try `ogrmerge.py` from gdal, it's really good for lots of files

Comment: Brillant, it worked perfectly. Thank you!!!